# PHP HOST directive

Tags: php, host, directive

I used [HOST=subdomain.mydomain.com] for some settings, but now I want to apply settings to everything except subdomain.mydomain.com.

This is my php.ini file:

```
[HOST=subdomain.mydomain.com]
display_errors = Off
```

I want disable_functions = phpinfo for all other domains except subdomain.mydomain.com. How can I do this?

Regards,
Kevin

P.S. I'm using Ubuntu, Apache2 and PHP5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say: "everything except"...I think what you want is the ability to specify a wildcard in the php.ini for the [[HOST=] section header](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.sections.php#ini.per-host). It doesn't appear to be a currently supported feature, based on the documentation.  You'll need to **list all of your hosts explicitly**, if you want to use this approach.

If you're not married to doing this a centralized php.ini, you can set this in Apache by [using the `php_value` directive](https://serverfault.com/questions/34078/how-do-i-set-up-per-site-php-ini-files-on-a-lamp-server-using-namevirtualhosts).  Set `disable_functions` in each virtual host to the value you want.